# Printing to pdf with QT

Tags: c++, qt, pdf

So I've been banging my head against the wall on how to print forms (instructions that pertain to a database element) on demand (and fill in things like date automatically) for a QT project I'm working on. Initially I was looking at the QT textdocument class which was perfect... except I wanted more CSS than it supported. Are there other ways to design a form and print in QT? Are there more complete html+css pdf generation libraries for c++?

Comment: QPrinter might be interesting for you. A similar topic is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660137/qt-how-to-print-information-via-qprinter

Comment: You pretty much have to use `QPainter` to render the form on a `QPrinter` that prints to a pdf. Alternatively, use a pdf generation library to generate the pdf from scratch.

Comment: Are you trying to generate a PDF file from some data in the database? Have you tried using any of these libraries: [CuteReport](https://cute-report.com/en), [QtRpt](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qtrpt/), [LimeReport](http://limereport.ru/en/index.php)? I remember that I've used QtRpt before, You can supply it a printer that uses [`QPrinter::PdfFormat`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#OutputFormat-enum) to save the report in a PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

You might find interesting to read this : https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_PDF

Comment: I am aware of this, but it's not a very helpful page.